# Light levels affecting IV curves for a Diode

Tags: diodes, pn-junction

I conducted an experiment to work out the saturation current under reverse bias for a diode in three different scenarios, ambient lighting, low light levels and high light levels. Is there an equation to relate light intensity to the current for a diode? Or is it likely that in the high light levels the heat from the lighting warmed up my diode and this is why the results have changed?

The diode was custom made in a cleanroom where I study for this experiment. The graph below shows the results I obtained for all 3, I wouldn't trust the results because they don't seem right compared with the 1n4004, oA90 and BZX zener diode we also tested with the same apparatus at the same time. 
[image: Graph of results]

Comment: Are you talking about an LED, a glass cased diode, or a standard black plastic diode?  Even better, what was the part number of the device you were testing on?  What were the results you saw?  What kind of light were you using?

Comment: @KrisBahnsen see my edit.

Comment: Labelling the axes would be a good idea.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon sorry had completely forgot about them been staring at graphs like that for about 3 hours so just naturally knew that current was y x was the voltage.

Comment: You say reverse bias - but your axes signs suggest fwd bias.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Yes because from the diode equation I = I_S (exp^(qV/kT)-1) and I_S is the reverse bias saturation current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading up on photodiodes will quite probably help.

Wereyour reference diodes in their original optically opaque outer package?
 Are your new diodes "bare"  / light exposed or protected from light?

---

[Wikipedia says this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode) re photodiodes.

Probably relevant is:

- Photoconductive mode: In this mode the diode is often reverse biased (with the cathode positive), dramatically reducing the response time at the expense of increased noise. This increases the width of the depletion layer, which decreases the junction's capacitance resulting in faster response times.

  The reverse bias induces only a small amount of current (known as saturation or back current) along its direction while the photocurrent remains virtually the same. For a given spectral distribution, the photocurrent is linearly proportional to the illuminance (and to the irradiance).[4]

  Although this mode is faster {than photovoltaic mode}, the photoconductive mode tends to exhibit more electronic noise.[citation needed] The leakage current of a good PIN diode is so low (<1 nA) that the Johnson–Nyquist noise of the load resistance in a typical circuit often dominates.

---

Probably relevant:

[image]

[Graph below from here.](http://www.rp-photonics.com/photodiodes.html) 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to heating, but it would be easier to say if you would post the results, or at least say if the current increases or decreases for the highest light level.

Being a semiconductor device, its conductivity should decrease if the temperature raises; but at the same time the threshold voltage decreases too, so it will start conducting earlier but with a lower steepness of the curve (this result is better explained by figure 3 of [this datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/1N4148_1N4448.pdf)).

Now, a diode can in theory react to an incident light: it's the case of the photodiode and the solar cell, which if reverse biased can generate a current proportional to the incident light. But these devices are particular types of p-n junctions, with a very thin and highly doped P-region which is exposed to the light being near the surface of the device and often covered with a lense or an anti-reflecting coating to maximize the absorbed light. Instead, yours seems to be a normal diode, where the case will probably filter most of the incident light; plus it's forward connected, making less likely that you are seeing a photoelectric phenomenon.